# Given only the "length of text/string", find the possible number of permutations

Tags: permutation, string-length

For example, given length = 4, the possible number/count of permutations = 24, 12, 6, 4, 1

1234 = 24 permutations
1123 = 12 permutations
1122 = 6 permutations
1112 = 4 permutations
1111 = 1 permutation

So,

Length 4 = 24, 12, 6, 4, 1
Length 5 = ?
Length 6 = ?

I would like to emphasize that I'm only given the "length of string" to permutate, and NOT given the actual string itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, if we know the string, we can compute the number of distinguishable permutations as n!/(a!b!...m!), where n is the length of the string and a, b, ..., m are the number of times each character appears in the string.  Thus, to get a list of all of the lengths, you would first need to compute the number of partitions of n (that is, the number of ways you can write n as an unordered sum of one or more not necessarily distinct positive integers) and then, for each partition, create the corresponding string and compute the number of distinguishable permutations of the characters in that string.